# Laravel with relation - Column not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

I use this query:

```
$clients = Client::with("types", "results")->where(function ($query) use ($issued, $mode, $request) {

      if (($request->get("filter"))) {
         $query->where('issued', $issued);
      }
    }
```

And `results` relation is:

```
public function results()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\ResultTest', 'client_id', 'unique_code');
    }
```

Table `ResultTest'` has `client_id` field and `issued`. It is joined with current table as:

```
Client.uqique_code = ResultTest.clients.
```

Now table `ResultTest` is empty.

It returns me an error:

```
Unknown column 'issued' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `clients` where (`issued` = 1))
```

I tried this way, that was recommended in answers below:

```
$clients->with(["results" => function($query) use ($issued, $request, $mode) {
            $query->where('issues', $issued);

            if (($request->get("mode"))) {
                $query->whereIn('mode', $mode);
            }

        }])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate();
```

It gives the same error:

```
 Unknown column 'issues' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `result_test` where `result_test`.`client_id` in (342074, 160374, 596433) and `issues` = 0)
```

Comment: Does the `issued` column exists in the `clients` table?

Comment: You're querying the `Client` model. It has no `issued` column.

Comment: No, i wrote i is in another table, I do relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long chat we found the following solution:

```
if($request->has('filter') || $request->has('mode')) { 
    $builder->whereHas('results', function ($query) use ($request) { 

        if (($request->has("filter"))) { 
            $query->where('issued', $request->get('filter')); 
        } 

        if (($request->has("mode"))) { 
            $query->whereIn('mode', $request->get('mode')); 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: That's not true. The order won't matter - it's still not going to work.

Comment: Do you mean use another `with`?

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't think this through. it's 0.30 here haha. I'm rewriting the answer right away.

Comment: Did a change now.

Comment: It looks bad: `}, "results"])->get();`.

Comment: I tried to use `->whereHas()` then  `->where()`. it did not help

Comment: This is a way to get all clients. with only the results loaded that have issued = $issued.

Comment: You offer to use `->with()->with()`

Comment: You said that `ResultTest` had a column `issued` So the new crash should not possible.

Comment: Yes, it has. But it is crashed

Comment: Yes, problem was also in this, but now your way gives me an error: `mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155557/discussion-between-mark-walet-and-opv).